# Handle multiple request in servlet and provide correct response to each request

Tags: jsp, session, servlets, request, client-server

I m working on a JSP project(not using any framework). I came to a point where I m not able to make out the cause of the problem. 
Implementation logic:
When a requests is send to servlet it call a function A to get the dynamic content from the database and pass it back to the client from where the request came.

Issue:
When multiple request comes to servlet, they fetch's the data from function A(It get the form details from the database) and pass the data to wrong client. SO in client machine wrong form draws.

How can handle request and response when multiple clients are involved. What can be the best practice to solve this issue. After searching internet I got singleton pattern and proxy class will help to resolve this issue ....Anyone have any idea please help me resolve this.

```
`// Getting value in jsp page
String val = request.getParameter("mod_value");
//calling function to get values from database
List<DrawForm> dataModel = QueryFunction.getPageDetails(val);
// Using this dataModel displaying the form
for(int i=0;i<dataModel.size();i++){
//Display form
}`





//QueryFunction Class
public class QueryFunction{
public static Connection connect = null;
public static CallableStatement statement = null;
public static ResultSet rset = null;

public static synchronized List<DrawForm> getPageDetails(String obj){

    List<DrawForm> dataModel = new ArrayList<>();

    try
    {   
        connect = DbConnection.GetConnection();
        statement = (CallableStatement)connect.prepareCall("{call 
        Get_form_template(?)}");
        statement.setString(1, obj);
        rset  = statement.executeQuery();
        while(rset.next()){
          DrawForm form = new DrawForm();
          // getting values in the array model
          dataModel.add(form);
        }                       
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        close();
    }       
    return dataModel;
}
private static void close() {
    if (connect != null) {
         try {
            connect.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

     if (rset != null) {
         try {
             rset.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

     if (statement != null) {
         try {
             statement.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


}
```

Comment: If you are getting the wrong information from the servlet then it has to do with your implementation. A request to a servlet automatically creates a seperate thread.

Comment: This can happen if you assign a user or client identifier to a member variable in your servlet class. In other words, don't keep any state in your servlet that varies from request to request. This _could_ explain the problem since servlets are singletons and shared across all requests. It's just a first guess because you haven't shown any code.

Comment: Dont know whats the issue...I ll describe the process....Client requests for a page...the request goes to another jsp(Lets say B). On Page B it call a function A, which retrieves the form details from the database and store the resultset in a model list and pass the List in return. Using that list the form is drawn on the Page B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issues come from static/shared fields. Just like the one example I provided.

While a thread is using connection,statement and resultset, so another thread could ocme and override them. This will cause inconsistency.

There is no logical way to have all fields as static here. For closing resources safe, you may use `try(){}` block.

```
//QueryFunction Class
public class QueryFunction{
//public static Connection connect = null;//god no!
//public static CallableStatement statement = null;
//public static ResultSet rset = null;

public static synchronized List<DrawForm> getPageDetails(String obj){

    List<DrawForm> dataModel = new ArrayList<>();

    try(Connection connect = DbConnection.GetConnection();CallableStatement statement = (CallableStatement)connect.prepareCall("{call Get_form_template(?)}");)
    {
        statement.setString(1, obj);
        try(ResultSet rset  = statement.executeQuery();){
          while(rset.next()){
            DrawForm form = new DrawForm();
            // getting values in the array model
            dataModel.add(form);
          }   
        }               
    }catch (Throwable wth) {
        wth.printStackTrace();
    }/*finally {
        close();
    }*/
    return dataModel;
}
//no need for this!, but if you insist, pass the connection, resultset and statement as input args
/*private static void close() {
    if (connect != null) {
         try {
            connect.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

     if (rset != null) {
         try {
             rset.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

     if (statement != null) {
         try {
             statement.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}*/


}
```

`try(){}` will automatically close any closable it guards.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you got threading issue.

By default java web engines(let say tomcat) handles the requests parallel. It means once there is a request for server, server accepts it while another requests are under progress.(also considering connection limit/pool, and backlogs)

The issue is about the A method you mentioned. I think something is used in global scope which is shareable with all requests/thread-calls.

Considering following example:

```
//the _c is shrable between threads
//this is not thread-safe
int _c=0;
public int method_a(){
    return _c++;//not thread safe!!!
}

//is called for each http calls
//request and response are associated to this call
//using them are safe
public void doGet(request,response){
int val=method_a();
//printing the val...
}
```

As above example, even if you call 100 http calls, this is possible the second called request responded with value 80(expected 1), and the last one returns with 8 (expected 99)

I think the business you do with method A you mentioned is not thread-safe.

You may mark the method_a [synchronized](https://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/06/java-threading.html#synctr) to validate it. But instead of sealing the parallel environment, you may find a correct solution to fix it.

You may share the code of your server, so we would find the issues more better.

Comment: I have placed the piece of code that I m using. Have a look at it

Comment: share the code of `QueryFunction.getPageDetails(val)`, looks like it's not thread-safe.
Also to make sure if it's related to this part call it by a sync block as `synchronized(sync_obj){QueryFunction.getPageDetails(val);for(...){...}}` (make sure all `dataModel` attribute references are also in sync block(like for look)
declare the `sync_obj` as a static field like `static final Object sync_obj=new Object();` make sure it's `static`

Comment: As guided I added synchronize keyword on the function. Its working correctly. Just need to confirm that will it cause any problem if say 3000 users hit at a same time. Like will it increase the loading time of form for users when multiple hit occurs.

Comment: The `synchronize` blocks just informed you the `getPageDetails` is not thread-safe. later for 3000 user you mentioned, all needed to be queued, and this is bad (yes could causes too much delay for users). Instead of bypass/mask the issue, fix it. `getPageDetails` should be coded thread-safe.

Comment: I have updated the code,  included getPageDetails() Code...Please have a look what

Comment: Issues becasue of static fields. Move all static fields (connection, callableStatement, and result set) inside the `getPageDetails` method. for close method, pass the required variables as input argument.
Better ways is using `try(<<closable>>){}` for connection, statement and resultset. I would also provide another answer now.